# Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient"

Tags: android, maven, google-play, google-play-services, google-advertising-id

I am using Maven to build my android project. In my Android project pom.xml, I have defined the dependency of google-play-service:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
  <type>apklib</type>
  <version>7</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

My project was built successfully. The android device I am using also has Google Play app installed. But when I start my app, I constantly get the following **error**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
```

What could be the reason for this error? How to fix it?

Comment: What is the status of this?

Answer (score 8):

I would highly suggest using `Gradle` over `Maven`.

However, make sure you using the correct import:

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0`

### Updated `ArtifactID` and `Version`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>play-services-ads</artifactId>
  <version>7.5.0</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

**Docs**: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Thanks. But I need to use maven as it is part of our legacy project, this is the precondition of my question.

Comment: @user842225 Why was this downvoted? I did answer your question